# WP_Query orderby

Tags: wp-query, order

I am trying to workout the best way to do a slightly abnormal orderby.

I have a query that returns 2 types (Post and Event). As expected by default it orders both, together, by publish date.

What I want is, posts to be ordered by publish date, events by `event->start_date`

I could just get them, loop over them and manually sort myself, but that seems counter intuitive.

Any help much appreceiated.

Cheers

Drogo

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding these two lines in your query:

```
'orderby' => 'publish_date',
'order' => 'ASC',
```

Comment: this is fine for the posts, but the events i want to use the `start_date` not the `publish_date`

Answer (score 0):

In the code below I assume that `event->start_date` is a post meta field on the Event post type.

```
'orderby' => array(
    'meta_value'   => 'ASC',
    'publish_date' => 'DESC'
),
'meta_key'  => 'start_date',
'meta_type' => 'DATE',
```

This assumes that the Posts don't have the `start_date` meta set, ie, that it's only present for the Events. Also I've assumed you want the Events in ascending order by their start_date and the Posts in descending publish_date order.

### Reference

- [WP_Query Order/Order By](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters)